# get next week start and end using jquery and moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I searched for this question and found there is a no answer on Stackoverflow.. So I decided to answer it...

This question helps if you need to get the start/end of next/last week with Monday as start of week.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used moment js for this ...  u can get it from [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
     /*
     all functions return moment() object.. <br>
     GetNextWeekStart().format('DD/MM/YYYY') to get 24/02/2014
     */

     function GetNextWeekStart() {
            var today = moment();
            //edited part
            var daystoMonday = 0 - (today.isoWeekday() - 1) + 7;       
            var nextMonday = today.subtract('days', daystoMonday);

            return nextMonday;
        }

        function GetNextWeekEnd() {
            var nextMonday = GetNextWeekStart();
            var nextSunday = nextMonday.add('days', 6);

            return nextSunday;
        }

        function GetLastWeekStart() {
            var today = moment();
            var daystoLastMonday = 0 - (1 - today.isoWeekday()) + 7;

            var lastMonday = today.subtract('days', daystoLastMonday);

            return lastMonday;
        }

        function GetLastWeekEnd() {
            var lastMonday = GetLastWeekStart();
            var lastSunday = lastMonday.add('days', 6);

            return lastSunday; 
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work (anymore?) - in `GetNextWeekStart` if `today` is Tuesday I get the following:
`> today.format('ddd, D-M-Y'); OUTPUT: 'Tue, 22-11-2016'`
`> daystoMonday = 0 - (today.isoWeekday() - 1) + 7; OUTPUT 6`
`> nextMonday = today.subtract('days', daystoMonday)`
`> nextMonday.format('ddd, D-M-Y') OUTPUT 'Wed, 16-11-2016'`
Shouldn't `nextMonday` be `today.add('days', daystoMonday)` instead?

Answer (score 164):

A little late to the party but here is the simplest way I've found to express starts/ends of weeks. The `isoWeek` argument starts weeks on Monday according to the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates), while `week` starts weeks **depending on your locale** (so probably either Sunday or Monday).

This week:

```
moment().startOf('isoWeek')
moment().endOf('isoWeek')
```

Next week:

```
moment().add(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek')
moment().add(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek')
```

Last week:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('isoWeek')
moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').endOf('isoWeek')
```

I like these constructions because they are incredibly readable. It's also easy to go back or forward any number of weeks by specifying how many weeks you want in `subtract` or `add`.

Comment: moment().endOf('week') should be moment().endOf('isoWeek')

Comment: Note that `.startOf("week")` is actually locale dependent, so it may not always be Sunday.

Comment: I am trying to get last week first day by:
 moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').startOf('week')
and I get sunday(which is ok), then I change my timezone to US&Canada and still get Sunday, when I expect to get Monday, why is that? @Dr.Acula

Comment: @OffirPe'er I don't think that Monday is the beginning of the week in US/Canada - you should try it with France/Germany or other european countries which do have their weeks starting on Monday.
BTW, this whole story of week start in moment.js is rotten to the core. Why not having a simple setter 'setWeekStartDay` or so instead of flawed locale which may not be the user's when running code server-side?

Answer (score 6):

This is specified in [the lang file](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/), you can include the `lang/en-au.js` or `lang/en-gb.js` file and set the desired language standard. Assume you're in the UK:

```
moment.lang('en-gb');
```

If you don't want to use a custom language, you can change it for the default US locale:

```
moment.lang('en-custom', {
    week: {
        dow: 1,
        doy: 6 // Adjust the first week of the year, depends on the country. For the US it's 6. For the UK, 4.
    }
});
```

Then you can do:

```
var date = '2014-03-24';

console.log('next start', moment(date).weekday(7).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 
console.log('next end', moment(date).weekday(13).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 

console.log('prev start', moment(date).weekday(-7).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 
console.log('prev end', moment(date).weekday(-1).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 

console.log('current start', moment(date).weekday(0).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 
console.log('current end', moment(date).weekday(6).format('DD/MM/YYYY')); 

/*
next start 31/03/2014 
next end 06/04/2014 
prev start 17/03/2014 
prev end 23/03/2014 
current start 24/03/2014
current end 30/03/2014
*/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WGXxn/3/

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the better (and more robust) way to do it. Especially because it supports locales.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Last week (get current week array list from momentjs)
    var sd = moment(currentWeekFd[0]).subtract(7, 'days').format();
    var ed = moment(currentWeekEd[6]).subtract(7, 'days').format();
    var lastWeekStratDay = moment(sd).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var lastWeekEndDay = moment(ed).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(lastWeekStratDay +', '+ lastWeekEndDay)

    //Next week
    var sd = moment(currentWeekFd[0]).add(7, 'days').format();
    var ed = moment(currentWeekEd[6]).add(7, 'days').format();
    var nextWeekStratDay = moment(sd).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var nextWeekEndDay = moment(ed).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(nextWeekStratDay +', '+ nextWeekEndDay)
```