# JavaScript for entering date based on value in an HTML text box

Tags: javascript

Is there a library for entering text values in an HTML text box which are then converted into a date?   For example, typing "Next Monday" puts next Monday's date in, "Next month" puts today's date + 1 month, "+4" puts today's date + 4 days, etc.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979051/find-next-instance-of-a-given-weekday-ie-monday-with-moment-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), which solves this sort of problem.

For natural language date-parsing, check out [chrono.js](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono).

```js
chrono.parseDate(document.getElementById("my-input").value)
```

For an input value of `"next week"`, this will return today's date plus seven days, in a `Date` type.