# I have two models in .net5 api application with one to many relationship. child model contains IFormFile property. I cannot bind this property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

Here are my models

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryDetail> CategoryDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller function is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromForm] Category category)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

the parameter inside the controller method is always null when I pass data through postman.

[image]

Comment: You need to parse the multipart/formdata request, take alook at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979051/find-next-instance-of-a-given-weekday-ie-monday-with-moment-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot pass two different content type data** to backend.

Your key name is wrong, it should be `CategoryDetails[0].File` not `CategoryDetails[0].files`. The key name should match the property name and it is case insensitive.

The correct way should be like below:

[image]

### Note:

If you post `CategoryDetails` with only `File` property, you need be sure remove `[ApiController]` and `[FromForm]` attribute. It is [a known github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28273) here. If you post `CategoryDetails` with several properties, no need to remove any attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation Rena. Its working now.

Comment: I also set different content type for different key and it worked correctly

Comment: Hi @UttamKar, where did you set? Do you mean you set `CONTENT TYPE` beside the `Value`. Maybe I do not explain to you clearly. `CONTENT TYPE` in the form-data panel is not used to set the content type. It just something like comment. `cannot pass two different content type data` means you set the `category` key with `json` string, and set `CategoryDetails[0].File` key with `multipart/form-data` type data. Model binding cannot  auto bind the model with two different content type data.

Comment: thank you @Rena for your explanation. I got it  what does "cannot pass two different content type data" mean.