# How to get nearest date ahead by day of week number?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, momentjs

I'm new to moment and I need to get the nearest date ahead by the number of the day of the week.

Depending on the current date, I need to get, for example:

```
const currentWeekDay = '4'; (14.04)
const preparedAlternativeDates = [
  { DAY: 1, VALUE: '18.04' },
  { DAY: 2, VALUE: '19.04'},
  { DAY: 3, VALUE: '20.04'},
  { DAY: 4, VALUE: '21.04'},
  { DAY: 5, VALUE: '15.04'},
  { DAY: 6, VALUE: '16.04'},
  { DAY: 7, VALUE: '17.04'},
];
```

I'm trying to use the script below but it doesn't work. Maybe there is an easier way to do this?

```
const ALTERNATIVE_DATES = Object.freeze([
  { DAY: 1, VALUE: null },
  { DAY: 2, VALUE: null },
  { DAY: 3, VALUE: null },
  { DAY: 4, VALUE: null },
  { DAY: 5, VALUE: null },
  { DAY: 6, VALUE: null },
  { DAY: 7, VALUE: null },
]);

const preparedAlternativeDates = ALTERNATIVE_DATES.map((alternativeDate: any) => {
  if (!alternativeDate.VALUE) {
    const alternativeDateDay = Number(alternativeDate.DAY);
    const currentWeekDay = Number(moment().isoWeekday());

    if (alternativeDateDay <= currentWeekDay) {
      alternativeDate.VALUE = moment().add(alternativeDateDay + currentWeekDay - 1, 'd').startOf('day');
    } else {
      alternativeDate.VALUE = moment().add(alternativeDateDay - currentWeekDay, 'd').startOf('day');
    }
  }

  return {
    day: alternativeDate.DAY,
    value: alternativeDate.VALUE
  };
});
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you explain the output you need exactly and the returned value of the function?

Comment: @SamySammour added an example above, thanks.

Comment: Look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979051/find-next-instance-of-a-given-weekday-ie-monday-with-moment-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just adjusted your code and tested the result. this should work for you:

```
const ALTERNATIVE_DATES = Object.freeze([
     { DAY: 1, VALUE: null },
     { DAY: 2, VALUE: null },
     { DAY: 3, VALUE: null },
     { DAY: 4, VALUE: null },
     { DAY: 5, VALUE: null },
     { DAY: 6, VALUE: null },
     { DAY: 7, VALUE: null },
  ]);

  const preparedAlternativeDates = ALTERNATIVE_DATES.map((alternativeDate: any) => {
     if (!alternativeDate.VALUE) {
        const wishedDay = Number(alternativeDate.DAY);
        const today = moment().isoWeekday();

        if (today < wishedDay) {
           alternativeDate.VALUE = moment().isoWeekday(wishedDay).format('DD.MM');
        } else {
           alternativeDate.VALUE = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(wishedDay).format('DD.MM');
        }
     }

     return {
        day: alternativeDate.DAY,
        value: alternativeDate.VALUE,
     };
  });
```

[image]

Comment: See the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979051/find-next-instance-of-a-given-weekday-ie-monday-with-moment-js